# AppGyver Steroids AJAX Call

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, steroids

For some reason I can't get AJAX cross domain calls to be made at all in my new steroids project. Weinre won't show them let alone any JS errors in console.

I've tested this code in Apache with a regular browser and the call is made and authentication even works. But when in Ad-Hoc mode nothing fires.

The `onclick` even fires because I get the alert's. I even get the alert before the ajax call, but ajax won't fire at all.

```
var baseUrl = 'http://www.domain.com/form/apiv1/index.php/';
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#login').click(function () {
        if($('#kairosid').val() <= '' || $('#kairosid').val() == '0') {
            alert('Please enter an ID to continue');
            return false;
        } else {
            alert('calling json');
            $.ajax({
                type: 'GET',
                url: baseUrl+'phoneauth/'+$('#kairosid').val()+'?callback=?',
                async: true,
                dataType: 'jsonp',
                jsonpCallback: 'processJSON',
                    crossDomain: true,
                headers: {
                    "Authorization": "Basic " + btoa(lkey+':'+lhash)
                },
                success: function ( data ) {
                    alert('done');
                    if(data == 'null' || data <= '') {
                        alert('Sorry, there was a problem with the request');
                    } else {
                        alert('loading '+data);
                        hashes = data;
                        var fields = ["phoneNumbers", "name"];
                        navigator.contacts.find(fields, apiLoginSuc, apiLogError);
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    });
});
```

Like I said, if I move this over to Apache and run there it runs just fine and calls the API and logs in just perfect.

In my PHP file I've placed this at the top to make sure:

```
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
```

Nothing at all shows up in Weinre:

[image]

But if I remove the HTTP from in front of the URL of course it works. With the HTTP it doesn't work. What gives here??

**EDIT:** Weinre log:

> 2014-06-05T19:57:38.795Z steroids:
>   DOMNotify.childNodeInserted([4,83,{"id":116,"nodeType":1,"nodeName":"SCRIPT","localName":"script","nodeValue":null,"childNodeCount":0,"attributes":["async","","src","http://www.domain.com/form/apiv1/index.php/phoneauth/7?callback=processJSON&_=1401998264894"]},null])